# Formula to Return Text in the Row of Largest Number

Tags: excel

Column A Has Text & Columns B, C & D contain numbers.

For Ex.)

```
A... …B  C   D    
John  4  6   2    
Dave  4  6   4    
Mike  4  5   1
Bill  2  5   9
```

I would like a cell to return the name in column A that has the Largest Number in Column B.  And if there are similar numbers, go to the next column and determine which is highest, and if that is tied go to the next column and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have this in an excel sheet as suggested by your tag, you can just use excel's sort feature and sort by the B column

Comment: ^^^^ sort by column B descending, Column C descending, and column D descending  then the one you want is on the top.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a formula with a an undefined number of iterations (i.e. calculations which may or may not passed over to a sub-calculation). Formulas like these are unwieldy and calculation intensive. Use a [tag:vba] [tag:user-defined-function] instead.

Answer (score 1):

We can de-conflict ties.
In **E1** enter:

```
=B1 + C1/(10*MAX(C:C))+D1/(100*MAX(D:D))
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(E:E),E:E,0))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1**

This is only good for **3** columns of numbers, but it is very easy to add additional de-confliction terms if necessary:

```
=B1 + C1/(10*MAX(C:C))+D1/(100*MAX(D:D))+E1/(1000*MAX(E:E))
```

Comment: This works great with 3 columns but the OP stated that it may go further: `go to the next column and so on`

Comment: @ScottCraner You are correct.  I will mention the limitation in my answer.

Comment: I was about to post my formula: `=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D1:D4)/(D1:D4 = AGGREGATE(14,6,D1:D4/(C1:C4=AGGREGATE(14,6,C1:C4/(B1:B4=MAX(B1:B4)),1)),1)),1))` when I realized it would possible go further than 3 columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Your formula is cool! ................I suggest posting it and mention the limitation.

Comment: Unfortunately upon further testing it does not work in all cases.  If we change C1 to 5 and D1 to 4 mine no longer works while yours still does.

Comment: @ScottCraner  It may be possible to re-cast my formula as an *array formula* and thus cover an unlimited number of terms ??

Comment: @ScottCraner  In retrospect, this is a lot more interesting than I thought at first.

Answer (score 0):

For an expandable number of rows/columns, use a helper row with the same number of columns as number columns in your data. The formulas below reference the following image (the data are in `A1:G7`):

[image]

`B9`-->`=MAX(B1:B7)`

`C9` (fill over the remaining columns to `G9`)-->

```
=MAX(IF(MMULT(--($B1:B7=$B9:B9),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS($B9:B9)))>0))=COLUMNS($B9:B9),C1:C7))
```

The following formula will give the answer (shown in `A9` above):

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(TRUE,(MMULT(--($B1:G7=$B9:G9),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS($B9:G9)))>0))=COLUMNS($B9:G9)),0))
```

---

**UPDATE WITH ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

Using a helper column instead, again referencing the image below (the data are in `A1:G7`):

[image]

`I1` (fill down to `I7`)-->

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(SIGN(B1:G1-$B$1:$G$7)*2^(COLUMN(G1)-COLUMN(A1:F1)),--(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(B1:G1)))>0))>0))
```

The following formula will give the answer (shown in `J1` above):

`=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(I1:I7),I1:I7,))`

As a bonus, notice that the helper column corresponds to the order that you would get from sorting the data by each column left-to-right. In other words, you could use the helper column to perform a formula-based multi-column sort on strictly numeric data. For the last image, entering the following array formula into a range with the same dimensions as `A1:G7` gives a descending sort on columns `B` through `G`:

```
=IF(A1:A7=A1:A7,INDEX(A1:G7,MATCH(ROW(A7)-ROW(A1:A7),I1:I7,0),))
```